# Can I change the pixel sizes in a world file?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdal-translate, pixel, world-file

I start with a dataset that has projection WGS84 and pixel size `0.000274658203125` degrees/pixel. I run `gdal_translate` to convert it to a PNG:

`gdal_translate dataset.tif output.png -of PNG -ot byte -scale -strict -co worldfile=yes`

Running `gdalinfo output.png` shows that the pixel size has lost precision and is now `0.000274658200000`.

However, I can edit the world file (`output.wld`) and change the X and Y pixel sizes to `0.000274658203125` and `-0.000274658203125`, respectively. Now, running `gdalinfo output.png` shows the proper pixel size.

So, my questions are:

- Is pixel size **only** controlled by the world file and can therefore be changed simply by editing the world file?
- If so, would it be better to construct my own world file in the first place?

Comment: That is slightly odd. In the case of PNG, yes the cell sizes are **only** dictated by the world file but this is not the case for all formats, a notable exception is GeoTIFF, also BIL/BSQ, both of these have origins and cell sizes that are not enforced by their world file (should one even exist). You would be safe to edit the world files for PNG, JPG, BMP to correct their loss of coordinate resolution.

Comment: If you multiply the size of your image as pixels by 0.000274658203125 and by 0.000274658200000, how big is the difference? It could be that 0.000274658203125 can not be expressed as a 32-bit floating point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format and therefore it gets rounded. The difference in pixel size is roughly 1/1000 of a millimeter if I count it right so not meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Michael Stimson in a comment on my original post, the PNG image format does not store GIS data such as pixel size, so the world file can be edited or generated manually as necessary.

In this case, the loss of precision described in my question was due to the fact that the [GDALWriteWorldFile function](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/ec7b85e6bb8f9737693a31f0bf7166e31e10992e/gdal/gcore/gdal_misc.cpp#L2113) happens to [round each value to 10 decimal places](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/ec7b85e6bb8f9737693a31f0bf7166e31e10992e/gdal/gcore/gdal_misc.cpp#L2126). In order to preserve the full precision, I ended up manually generating the world file for each PNG.